# Why in Matlab .* operator is faster than * for a scalar in some case?

Tags: performance, matlab

Consider the following code :

```
a=rand(10000); b=rand(10000);
tic; 2*(a<b); toc;
tic; 2.*(a<b); toc;
```

The result is :

```
Elapsed time is 0.938957 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.426517 seconds.
```

Why the second case is twice faster than the first case ?

Edit :
I obtain the same result with any size of the matrix, whatever the order you test it, with

```
(a<b).*3.56 vs (a<b)*3.56
```

for example, but not with

```
(a.*b)*2 vs (a.*b).*2
```

or

```
(a*b)*2 vs (a*b).*2
```

It seems there is a link with the logical array, because I have the same result with

```
(a&b)*2 vs (a&b).*2
```

Computer : R2015b, Windows 10 x64

Comment: You should also check `(uint8(a)*2` vs `(uint8(a)).*2`. It might not be booleanness, but rather integerness. Also, `c=a<b; c(:)*2` vs `c(:).*2`.

Comment: There is no difference with `(uint8(a)*2` vs `(uint8(a).*2`, but I see the same difference with `c=a<b; c(:)*2`  vs `c(:).*2` .

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, I've updated my answer with the extra information. I still don't get a definitive answer, but possibly only a mathworks employee could give one. But what you found also means that probably `mtimes` should fall back on `times` for scalar input.

Comment: Thank you for the accept, although I'm not quite sure I've answered your question:) Anyway, you could try using the undocumented (see www.undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-function)  `feature('JIT','off')` or `feature('accel','off')`, maybe it'll be clear where the speed-up is coming from (the `'JIT'` case is supposed to modify a subset of the `'accel'` case.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest performing a more strict check of performance. Put your test in a named function to let MATLAB optimize both pieces of code, and run both codes several times, choosing the quickest runtime. My hunch is that they should take the same amount of time, although I can't check right now with reasonable matrix sizes. Here's what I'd do:

```
function product_timing(N)

a=rand(N);
b=rand(N);

tmin=inf;
for k=1:10
    tic;
    res1=2*(a<b);
    t=toc;
    
    if t<tmin
        tmin=t;
    end
end

disp(tmin);


tmin=inf;
for k=1:10
    tic;
    res2=2.*(a<b);
    t=toc;
    
    if t<tmin
        tmin=t;
    end
end
```

### Update

On my R2012b there doesn't seem to be a marked difference between the two methods. However, as others have indicated, R2015b with its new execution engine makes all the difference.

While I'm still unsure about the answer, let me collect the feedback from [@x1hgg1x](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5799721/x1hgg1x) (comments on both this answer and question) and [@LuisMendo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo) ([in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28178740#28178740)), just to elaborate on my ignorance:

- `c*3.56` is an integer factor (number of threads?) of times slower than `c.*3.56` (with any scalar) if `c` is `logical`, but not if `c` is `uint8` or `double`
- the same holds true for vectors, not just square matrices

As it's stated [on a MATLAB product page](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/matlab-execution-engine/):

> Run your programs faster with the redesigned MATLAB® execution engine.
>
> The improved architecture uses just-in-time (JIT) compilation of all
> MATLAB code with a single execution pathway. The engine offers
> improved language quality and provides a platform for future
> enhancements.
>
> Specific performance improvements include those made to:
>
> ...
>
> Element-Wise Math Operations
>
> The execution of many element-wise math operations is optimized. These
> operations are element-by-element arithmetic operations on arrays such
> as the following:
>
> `>> b = ((a+1).*a)./(5-a);`

However, looking at the docs of `.*` and `*`, I can't see too much information relating to the problem. A note from [array vs matrix operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html) concerning array operations like `.*`:

> If one operand is a scalar and the other is not, then MATLAB applies
> the scalar to every element of the other operand. This property is
> known as scalar expansion because the scalar expands into an array of
> the same size as the other input, then the operation executes as it
> normally does with two arrays.

And the [doc of the matrix product `*`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) says

> If at least one input is scalar, then A*B is equivalent to A.*B and
> is commutative.

As we see, the *equivalence* of `A*B` and `A.*B` is arguable. Well, they are equivalent mathematically, but something strange is going on.

Due to the above notes, and the fact that the performance difference only arises for `logical` arrays, I would consider this an undocumented feature. I would've thought that it's related to `logical`s only occupying 1 byte each, but the speed-up doesn't manifest with `uint8` arrays. I suggest that since `logical`s actually contain information in a single bit, some internal optimization is possible. This still doesn't explain why `mtimes` doesn't do this, and it's surely related to the internal workings of `times` vs `mtimes`.

One thing is sure: `times` doesn't actually fall back on `mtimes` for scalar operands (maybe it should?). Since in R2012b the whole effect is missing, I believe that the optimized array operations of the new execution engine mentioned above treat logical arrays separately, allowing the special case of `scalar.*logical_array` to be sped up, but the same optimization is missing from `mtimes`.

Comment: I get a different result on R2015b, Win10 x64 (with k from 1 to 100):

    product_timing(10000)
    0.8183 (1st)

    0.2113 (2nd)

The difference is greater than precedently.

Comment: @x1hgg1x wow, interesting:) What about `N=1000`? That should be comparable to my comparison (unfortunately I don't have enough free memory right now to test your test case). Also: you should try swapping the order of the two types of code, to have `.*` first. I hope this doesn't change the result, but in R2015b all sorts of optimization magic can happen.

Comment: @x1hgg1x also, does `(a<b).*2` have the same speed? I wonder whether `2.*` is interpreted as `(2).*` or `(2.)*`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: It's definitely not `(2.)*`, the `.` is not an operator, it's part of the literal. That would violate any common how programming languages work. I am not able to find an example with multiplication where you can see the difference, but `2.^magic(3)` and `(2.)^magic(3)` demonstrates it with power.

Comment: I obtain the same result with any value of N, with (a<b).*3.56 vs (a<b)*3.56 for example, but not with (a.*b)*2 vs (a.*b).*2, or (a*b)*2 vs (a*b).*2. It seems there is a link with the logical array, because I have the same result for (a&b)*2 vs (a&b).*2.

Comment: @Daniel wonderful, thanks for the simple decisive example (I couldn't come up with one).

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Another example for multiplication: `x=serial('com1');2.*x;`. The error message tells you the function name.

Comment: @Daniel indeed, thanks, and also `x={1}; 2.*x;`. But you had me already convinced with your first example:)

Comment: @rayryeng thank you:) I'm still not satified though, and most of the factual information comes from others, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

For background, the `*` operator is a matrix operator, while `*.` is an element-wise operator (see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html).

In your test, a and b are random 1000x1000 matrices which evaluate to a logical 1000x1000 matrix that you want are scaling with these two approaches.  Apart from having a developer at Mathworks tell us what is happening under, I think we can only speculate as to what is happening to cause the difference (and answer your question).

Since, we are not supposed to speculate on these answers, I'll officially stop here.  However, it is interesting what you stumbled upon all the same.

So, unofficially, I suspect you have found some additional overhead MATLAB is implementing to handle matrix operations with the `*` operator, which are short-circuited or bypassed in the element operator.

Consider the following

```
c = a<b;
tic; d*(c); toc;  % case 1
tick;d.*(c); toc; % case 2
```

where `a` and `b` are defined by your code above, and `d` is left as an unknown value for the sake of explanation, next.

When multiplying matrices, the number of columns in the first matrix needs to match the number of rows in the second matrix.  `c` is going to be a 1000x1000 matrix, right, so `d` either needs to have the 1000 columns (e.g. `size(d,2)==1000`) or it needs to be a scalar.  In the second case, `d` must be a scalar (or an error will be thrown).

Also, there may be some additional prepping (not much, but some) for how you are going to order your matrices when doing multiplication so you can get your sums correctly for each location in the final produce.  Here, we know that `d==2` and it is a scalar, so the multiplications can be done in place. However, we know that because we see it.  I don't think the multiplication algorithm is taking that as a corner case here - to see that `d` is a scalar value.  If it is, it would/should just call the `*.` routine.  And, perhaps this is what is happening, and we are just getting some level stack overhead.  Unofficially, of course.

Comment: Your explanation is interesting, but there is a difference only if c is a logical array (see my edit).

Comment: That is interesting - thanks for the follow-on edit.

Comment: @x1hgg1x Yes, you can time the different operations, but I don't think we can answer your question as to "why" this is the case without looking under the hood.  Still, it is fun to see how you are able to paint a better picture of how things are being handled differently down there; particularly with the logical array results (e.g. a<b or a&b as you added in your edit).  Good research on your part!

Answer (score -1):

Yes,".*" is faster on 2015b between a scalar and a logical array:

```
a = rand(10000); b = rand(10000);
timeit(@()2*a)
timeit(@()2.*a)

timeit(@()2.*(a>b))
timeit(@()2*double(a>b))
timeit(@()2*(a>b))
```

Comment: What results did you get?

Comment: With your code I obtained in order : 1) 0.3137,  2) 0.3135,  3) 0.5059,  4) 0.8972,  5) 0.9708

Comment: @x1hgg1x, that's why I said ".*" is faster between a scalar and a logical array before you and Andras Deak